# Formulário não envia POST

Tags: php, codeigniter, arquivo, upload, post

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de importação de dados de **XLS para MySQL**. O sistema praticamente está pronto. Fiz um teste com um arquivo `xls` de 24kb e exportou com sucesso, sem erro algum. O problema é que fui testar agora com um arquivo `xls` com 1MB e o erro que ocorre é que parece que não envia o `POST` para o servidor, sendo que ele precisa enviar para eu fazer o upload do arquivo. O meu limite máximo para envio no servidor é de **50MB**

**Formulario**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Banco de dados</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" name="arquivo" class="form-control">
      <small>Envie no formado .xls</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line line-dashed b-b line-lg pull-in"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitFile" value="Iniciar Importação">
```

**Upload**

```
if($this->input->post('submitFile')){

    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/tmp/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
    $config['file_name'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    $config['overwrite'] = true;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('arquivo')){
        redirect('import/database');
    }else{
        redirect('import/upload');
    }

  }
```

Comment: Ele envia o xls para o mesmo arquivo php?

Comment: sim, tanto o de 24kb e o de 1mb estão para o mesmo arquivo, diretório.

Comment: você diz que parece que não envia o post para o servidor, já tentou setar o `max_size` $config['max_size'] = 10240; (10mb) ou alguma configuração no seu php.ini?

Comment: Já tentei sim, colocar 10MB e no meu php.ini está post_max_size = 50m

Comment: E também precisa setar o "upload_max_filesize" (upload_max_filesize = 50M).